# How to find the sum that are not geometric series or telescoping series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}$

How do I find the sum above, and I am confused that how to find the sums which are not geometric series or telescoping series.

I know Taylor series and Taylor expansion, but is it possible to reverse it from the series?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining the infinite sum $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3065308/determining-the-infinite-sum-sum-limits-n-0-infty-frac-1n2n1) (asked zillion times)

Answer (score 0):

You simply have the Taylor Series for $\arctan(x)$ at $x=1$
$$\arctan(x) = x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5} ...$$
Put $x=1$,
we get the required sum to be $\arctan(1) = \pi/4$

Hope this helps

Comment: helpful, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$$ 
We want $f(1)$. What is $df/dx $?

Comment: $\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{1-(-x^2)^\infty}{1+x^2}$

It should be $\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ if x<1

But now x=1, could we really conclude  $\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ ?

Comment: The solution was already posted. However, I was wondering how to proceed form here. We obtain $f^{\prime}(x) = \sum_{k\geq 0} (-x^2)^k = 1/(1+x^2), x<1$. How do we conclude now?

Comment: The integral of $1/(1+x^2)$ is arctan.  To make it rigorous, you might find the remainder term and show it approaches zero.